# Facebook return com.facebook.sdk error 5 during Friend Wall Post

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my App I used Facebook sdk 3.1 and using that I try to do wall Post.
Using This Code Snippet I can successfully wall post Image and Message on Friend Wall and on my own wall.I just change **me/photos** and  **friendId/photos**.

```
-(IBAction)postPhoto:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"baby.jpg"];
    NSArray *frndArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Friend ID", nil];
    [self postImageOnFriendsWall:image FriendsArray:frndArray];
}

-(void)postImageOnFriendsWall:(UIImage*)image FriendsArray:(NSArray*)friends
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


    // if we don't have permission to announce, let's first address that
    if ([appDelegate.session.permissions  indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound)
    {

        NSArray *permissions =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",@"manage_friendlists", nil];

        [FBSession setActiveSession:appDelegate.session];

        [[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error)
         {
             if (!error)
             {
                 // have the permission
                 [self postImageOnFriendsWall:image FriendsArray:friends];
             }
             else
             {
                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription                                                                                                delegate:nil                                                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alertView show];
             }
         }];

    }
    else
    {

        //post image
        for (id<FBGraphUser> user in friends)
        {

            NSString* szMessage = @"Check out!";

            NSString *userID = user;
            NSLog(@"trying to post image of %@ wall",userID);
            NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [postVariablesDictionary setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"picture"];
            [postVariablesDictionary setObject:szMessage forKey:@"message"];

            [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",userID] parameters:postVariablesDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)

             {

                 if (error)
                 {
                     //showing an alert for failure
                     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook"
                                            message:error.localizedDescription                                                                                      delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alertView show];
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     //showing an alert for success
                     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Facebook"
                                            message:@"Shared the photo successfully"                                                                                                delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alertView show];
                 }
             }];

        }
    }
}
```

For Message wall post I used **me/feed** and its work but for Friend **friendID/feed** will give me **Error: HTTP status code: 403** and In alert box i got **com.facebook.sdk error 5**.

So Please guide me m I doing anything wrong?, or What I have to do for wall post.

Comment: i think you dont have all permissions activated.

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/ - which says, "Note: If you are posting to a friend's timeline or wall, you must use the Feed Dialog." So you can't post friendId/feed. To do that you need to use the feed dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is solution,

I update my FB SDK 3.1 to 3.2 then import

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

then update

```
[[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                   completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {}];
```

in place of

```
[[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error){}];
```

and update

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           @"FRIEND ID", @"to",
                                           @"text change", @"caption",
                                           @"this is test message on ur wall", @"description",
                                           @"https://website.com/share", @"link",
                                           @"http://website.com/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
                                           nil];
            [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                   parameters:params
                                                      handler:
             ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)

            {}];
```

in place of

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",userID] parameters:postVariablesDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){}];
```

and i got Dialog box and after click on share Successfully post on FRIEND's Wall.

Hope this snippet help someone else.

Comment: Thank you for your usefull hint.@ C Abernathy

Comment: @Harin Is there a way to post in background? without displaying dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. Try this one:

```
me?fields=friends.fields(feed)
```